# Reading XML using XMLTABLE in Oracle vs XML reading via SSIS in SQL Server

Tags: oracle, ssis

We are in the process of migrating MS SQL Server to Oracle. Currently we are processing XMLs (with size of 300MB) via SSIS in SQL Server and it takes only seconds. But in Oracle, reading the same XML via `XMLTABLE` takes minutes. Is there any better approach in Oracle to read XMLs so that we can reduce the time. Also , I am wondering how SSIS is taking only seconds? Is it because SSIS working on separate thread?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using, and are you passing the data to Oracle or are you storing it in Oracle? If you're storing it in Oracle, what kind of XMLType storage model are you using? Depending on the version there may be multiple ways of storing XML, and [the best answer may depend on which storage model you're using](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/choice-of-XMLType-storage-and-indexing.html#GUID-60132193-FCBB-4A7F-AA11-53CB660F67AF).

Comment: This kind of performance difference for 300Mb data may be also a DOM against SAX difference, but to parse XML using SAX in ORACLE DB you need to deploy your own Java procedure.

Comment: @p3consulting , Any idea how to use SAX and deploy our own Java procedure.

Comment: Both questions have answers on this site (java tag) or dba associate site regarding the deploy of Java procedure in ORACLE.